# For what values n is the group $S_n$ cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

So, a friend of mine and I were confused about when $S_n$ is cyclic.

I thought $S_n$ is cyclic for $S_{2n}$ where $n$ is an integer and abelian for $n \leq 2$ but my friend said its the other way around.

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: What do you mean by $S_n$? If it is the permutation group on $n$ symbols you are both wrong. See the answer.// and you are wrong regardless the group since it is  impossible for a group to be cyclic while not abelian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that every cyclic group is also Abelian.

For $n \geq 3$, $(12)$ and $(23)$ do not commute so $S_n$ is non-Abelian (and thus is not cyclic).

For $n < 3$, $S_n$ is cyclic (and hence Abelian).

Comment: Makes sense. thanks for telling me that every cyclic group is also abelian