# Showing $\mathbb{Z_n}$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I'm reviewing my notes and I just realized that I can't think of how to show that a particular integer mod group is abelian. I know how to do it with symmetric but not with integers themselves.

For example, lets say I was asked to show $\mathbb{Z_5}$ is abelian.

I know for symmetric groups, lets say $S_5$ i can pick two elements in $S_5$, for example (123),(23) and if (123)(23)=(23)(123) then I know it is abelian but how would I go about the integers?

Comment: Again take two elements - but what are the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5$? They are the residue classes $[0]$, $[1]$, $[2]$, $[3]$, $[4]$. Therefore, we want to check e.g. if $[1] + [3] = [3] + [1]$. Indeed, both are equal to $[4]$. Also, please note that $(123)(23) \not= (23)(123)$ as elements of the symmetric group $S_5$. In fact, $S_5$ is not an abelian group.

Comment: Yeah for $\mathbb{S_5}$ i meant the procedure, sorry, the way I worded can be misleading. I'll fix it.

Comment: Fancy letters are not used for the symmetric groups. We use $S_n$, not $\mathbb S_n$

Comment: Oh I shall fix that too then! Thanks!

Comment: Also, just to be clear: it takes more than demonstrating two elements commute, to show that an entire group is abelian (I.e, finding two permutations that commute would not make $S_n$ abelian).

Comment: I didn't mean the whole $S_n$, I meant particular symmetric groups like i said $S_5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symmetric group $S_n$ is not abelian for $n\geq 3$ since $(12)(123)=(23)$ and $(123)(12)=(13)$.

On the other hand any cyclic group is abelian. This is because in reality every element $m$ can be thought of as $\underbrace{1+1+1\dots+1}_{\text{m times}}$.

And so

$m+n=(\underbrace{1+1+1\dots+1}_{\text{m times}})+(\underbrace{1+1+1\dots+1}_{\text{n times}})=(\underbrace{1+1+1\dots+1}_{\text{n times}})+(\underbrace{1+1+1\dots+1}_{\text{m times}})=n+m$

Where the equality in the middle is just the associativity rule.

Answer (score 0):

Note that symmetric groups are *not* Abelian unless $n < 3$.  See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186094/for-what-values-n-is-the-group-s-n-cyclic/1186099#1186099) for a proof.

As for how to see that $\Bbb{Z}_n$ is Abelian, note that the group $\Bbb{Z}$ is Abelian.  Therefore, any quotient group of $\Bbb{Z}$ by a subgroup is also Abelian.  Since $\Bbb{Z}_n \cong \Bbb{Z} / n \Bbb{Z}$, we are done.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to show, for any cyclic group $G = \langle a\rangle$, is that:

$a^ka^m = a^ma^k$ for any integers $k,m$.

This takes care of $\Bbb Z$ *and* $\Bbb Z_n$ (for any $n$) "all at once".

Can you show how to leverage the "rules of exponents" and commutativity of addition in the integers, here?